# Github website hosting, handling incorrect subpages

Tags: url, github, github-pages

I have hosted a simple singlepage HTML/CSS website on github. I wanted to redirect incorrect subpages (ie mysite.com/m) to redirect to the homepage (mysite.com) as the default route. Can this be achieved on a static site on github?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `/m/index.html` file containing :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>Redirecting...</title>
<link rel=canonical href="/index.html">
<meta http-equiv=refresh content="0; url=/index.html">
<h1>Redirecting...</h1>
<a href="/index.html">Click here if you are not redirected.</a>
<script>location='/index.html'</script>
```

Comment: Well could a more general term be used for all wrong routes redirecting to a specific page as we define in Angularjs. Its basically a static site so don't want to put in Angularjs